# Issue with div set to display: table-cell;

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {margin:0;padding:0;outline:0;border:0;}
aside {background:red;width:40%;display:table-cell;}
.two {width:40%;background:blue;display:table-cell;}
.one {width:30%;background:green;display:table-cell;}
#wrapper {display:table;width:100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<aside>
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; border: 2px solid orange;">

</div><!-- / -->
</aside>
<section class="two">
Text
</section>
<section class="one">
Text
</section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a JSFiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/jtmkrueger/Aza47/

How can I get the content in the cells to always be valigned to the top in this situation?  Notice that 'text' in the second and third boxes is pushed down...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `vertical-align: top;` style.

See the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aza47/1/).

Comment: Nice, I knew there was an elegant solution to the problem.