# Strange behavior with table-cell layout and empty div

Tags: html, css

I just stumbled over a very strange behavior with a layout which uses the `table-cell` css property. I tried the following code in current FF, Safari and Chrome. The behavior is the same everywhere.

**My questions** is whether someone knows why this happens. Is it a browser bug or a defined behavior? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451626/issue-with-div-set-to-display-table-cell) question which has a hint on how to solve the problem, but I would rather like to know why this is happening in the first place. I think other people would also like to know.

**Problem:** If I comment in the `&nbsp;` in the second table-cell, everything is fine. If, however the *div* stays empty the content of the two other cells has something like an "offset-top". This offset has the same dimension as the height of the middle cell. I.e. the content of the outer cells is shifted to the bottom. I added two screenshot *div_not_empty.png* and *div_empty.png*.

thanks

**Update**
I forgot the screenshots. Here they are:
[image: Div is empty]
[image: Div is not empty]

---

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Strange behavior with table-cell formatting</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      #table {
        display:    table;
        background: #efefef;
      }
      div.cell {
        display:    table-cell;
      }
      #c1 div.content {
        width:    200px;
      }
      #c2 {
        border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
      }
      #c2 div.content {
        height:   150px;
        width:    150px;
        background: #aaa;
        vertical-align: bottom;
      }
      #c3 {
        width:    200px;
        border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="table">
      <form id="c1" class="cell">
        <div class="content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.
        </div>
      </form>
      <div id="c2" class="cell">
        <div class="content">
          <!-- &nbsp; -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="c3" class="cell">
        <div class="content">
           Dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
           quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
           aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
           dolor in reprehenderit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's got to do with the way that `vertical-align: bottom` is calculated - see the [mdc docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align), when applied to table cells, `bottom` "Aligns the bottom padding edge of the cell with the bottom of the row".

When the table cell has no content, padding is not drawn in the box (i.e. when when 0, if there is content, the browser calculates where the padding would be).

With a `&nbsp;` element, there is content to use as the basis for the alignment; without it you'll notice the browsers line the bottom of the element itself up with the bottom of the first line of content in the other elements.

re: the question you link to, using `vertical-align: top` works because the layout is calculated based on the top of the block elements, not the content they contain.

A simple fix for the issue is to add padding to the .content divs in your stylesheet, which then causes them to render as if they have content, meaning you don't need to have `&nbsp;`'s in your code when there's nothing to display:

```
  div.content {
    height:   150px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
  }
```

Try this and you'll see it behaves as you expect.

So; not really a browser bug, as the browser is trying to calculate the position based on the content (or, bottom of padding) of an element, and the element has no content. Possibly an unintended side-effect of the spec in this case though.

On a related note, your css rule `div.cell` isn't matching the first 'cell' which is a `form` element. It's working because all elements inside a `display: table` element have `display: table-cell` applied automatically, but not the best.

Comment: thx, that makes it much more clear. Yes, the form element is there, because I copied the wrong version out of my editor, sorry for that.